# Static Shift Registers for Serial In / Parellel Out Operation

Tags: digital-logic

I'm looking for an 8bit static shift register with serial in-parellel out operation but can't seem to find one . Can anyone help me with this, thank you !

Comment: What about 74HC595? Not sure if it is static, though.

Comment: @Ricardo: Although the Apple I used dynamic shift registers, I would be surprised if any "standalone" dynamic shift register chips have been made in the last 25 years (it's vaguely conceivable that some chips might use dynamic shift registers internally because the per-bit cost would be slightly below that of static RAM and the interfacing cost well below that of dynamic RAM, but dynamic logic of any sort--other than DRAM--is rare).

Comment: The data sheet for this chip says minimum switching frequency is around 38Mhz. Does this mean I really cant operate it down to DC ?

Comment: If you look at parameter t(w) (pulse width) in the data sheet, there is no maximum specified. Therefore, clock pulses can be infinitely long (DC).

Answer (score 1):

To add to Wouter's answer and to answer a comment by the OP: -

[image]

\$F_{MAX}\$ is guaranteed to be a minimum of 35MHz at a supply of 6V and at a supply voltage of 4.5V it's guaranteed to be at least 30MHz.

This device can be clocked statically i.e. at 0.1Hz or 0.0000000001 mHz or however long you want to take between clock edges. Ditto the 74AC version and all shift registers that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

The 74HC(T)595 is very popular.